# Why isn't my custom UICollectionViewController's GetCell method called

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have a storyboard set up like so:

[image]

As you can see, I have a home screen. It has access to a navigation controller. It has two ContainerViews, one used as a sidepane, the other as the main content. I plan to swap things into this main content container as I need them.

One of the things I would like to show in this container, when it is selected from the sidepane, is a CollectionView of cells that show people. Each cell has a photo and the person's details.

The best code example I could find for CollectionView was the Xamarin [StateRestoration](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/StateRestoration) sample project. It includes a storyboard. I have followed the recipe as best I can while working around my own specific storyboard.

**The problem** now is that the `GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)` method used to populate each cell in the CollectionView is not being called. As far as I know I'm supposed to instantiate the CollectionViewController's Datasource property. I've tried this in AppDelegate and in the ViewDidLoad of my CollectionViewController itself, and GetCell is still not getting called. Why is this?

Any help is appreciated! Ask me to edit if you need more information.

Comment: Have you also set the delegate property of UICollectionView?

Comment: I don't think so. I couldn't work out how this was done in the sample project. Can you suggest a way to do this, for me to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both datasource and the delegate. As you've mentioned you've set the datasource. To set the delegate open up the storyboard in xcode, select `UICollectionView` and control drag to the its parent view controller. Have a look at this gif.

[image]

Also make sure you implement `IUICollectionViewSource` interface in your target view controller

```
public partial class DetailViewController : UIViewController, IUICollectionViewSource
    {

        protected DetailViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }


        public nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return 10;
        }

        public UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("PersonCell", indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell;
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

You can also do this programmatically. Enter the storyboard, in Widget properties set the name for the `UICollectionView` - `PersonCollection`. Then in code behind view controller override `ViewDidLoad` and set `WeakDelegate` and `WeakDataSource` (weak because we definitely not want to create cyclic reference and memory leaks for iOS)

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            PersonCollection.WeakDataSource = this;
            PersonCollection.WeakDelegate = this;
        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do I do this in Xamarin?

Comment: Are you on Windows Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. Ctrl and drag doesn't work in the document outline.

Comment: Well my GetItemsCount method is now being called! But still not GetCell

Comment: Ahhh! I implemented GetItemsCount properly and GetCell is now getting called!